# Access objects from another class

Tags: python, odoo

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong here. I'm trying to access an object that I have in another object.

So for res.partner I made a custom module that gives an extra field named xx_manager.

Now in sale.order I want to check if the field is empty or not, so I thought I'd just have to do this:

```
    def action_button_confirm(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    partner = self.pool.get('res.partner')
    if not partner.xx_manager:
        raise osv.except_osv(_('Warning!'), _('No account manager has been set'))
    return super(sale_order, self).create(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

The error that I'm getting:

```
AttributeError: 'res.partner' object has no attribute 'xx_manager'
```

My custom module for res.partner:

```
class res_partner(osv.osv):
_inherit="res.partner"

_columns = {
    'xx_manager': fields.many2one('res.users', string='Account Manager'),
}
```

Comment: So, are you getting an error message, or what?

Comment: @Kevin Yes, I've included it in the post, sorry for the missing information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah because you forget to browse the current record. So browse the current record and take partner id from it and than check partner condition as you want.

try with this code

```
def action_button_confirm(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    partner = self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context=context)
    if partner.partner_id and not partner.partner_id.xx_manager:
        raise osv.except_osv(_('Warning!'), _('No account manager has been set'))
    return super(sale_order, self).action_button_confirm(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
```

Comment: But this code assumes your working in the class where the method is right? Cause I need to method to be in sale.order and I'm getting the xx_manager from res.partner

Comment: yeah you can do that, in `sale.order` you have `partner_id,` it has relationship with `res.partner` so take partner_id form it and check the condition on of it.

Comment: If I do so I get the following error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: The method def_action_button is in the sales.order class

Comment: flow is wrong, try with create method don't do on that method. i will update create method so you will get better idea.

Comment: The general idea is that when someone wants to confirm a quotation it needs to check if the customer has a manager set (xx_manager). Hence I thought I should overwrite the confirm button in Quotations so that when they press "Confirm Sale", it check the above for a manager.

Comment: Yes I did try it, you forgot the self after sale.order but it works to an extend. So when no manager has been setup it gives the warning, but when I go and setup a manager and come back to that quotation it won't make an invoice, it just stays at the quotation